# how to convert datetine in to unix time with javascript or vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have a table store db, it include row url.
i want after creating record ,data in row url will + datetime create recordk format string number Unixtime.
in laravel 5.6,have function .time() converted into unix time,return 10 keyword. so
in javascript or Vuejs how to do it ?
I did like this in vuejs.
help me !

```
function(){
     var name = this.page.name.replace(/ /g,'');
     var date = new Date();
     var unixtime = b*1000;
     var url = this.page.url = name + unixtime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Date.now()` if you need the current timestamp, or `dateInstance.getTime()` to get the timestamp of any other date instance.

```
function(){
     var name = this.page.name.replace(/ /g,'');
     var url = this.page.url = name + Date.now();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment(date).format('x')